# Nearest neighbor analysis, write multiple columns to table

Tags: qgis, nearest-neighbor

I have a table (table1) containing 800 points that I want to join with a table (table2) containing only 10 points. The idea is that the points in table2 are assigned to the points in table 1 based on nearest neighbor analysis. This can be easily done using, for example, the NNJoin plugin in QGIS.

However, this plugin only adds a column containing the distances to the nearest points to table1. But that's not what I need, for I want to add multiple columns with information from table2 to table1 based on the nearest neighbor analysis.

So in short, how can I add multiple columns filled with data from table2 to table1, based on nearest neighbor analysis?

Edit:

A small reformulation, to clarify things a bit: I want to add all attributes from table2 to table1, based on nearest neighbor analysis. So not only the distance, but also all other attributes from table 2.

Comment: The NNJoin plugin also adds the attributes of the joined dataset: "The result layer will contain all the attributes of both the input and join layers plus a new attribute “distance” that contains the distance between the joined features. The attributes from the join layer will get a prefix (the default is “join_”, but this can be set by the user). If a join prefix is not used, attributes from the join layer that have the same name as attributes in the input layer will not be included in the output layer." (http://arken.umb.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/NNJoin/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **Distance to nearest hub** tool from:

*Processing Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector analysis tools > Distance to nearest hub*

Make sure you have a unique value for a field in *table2* as this would be used to identify each point in this layer when calculating distances from points in *table1*

[image: Distance to nearest hub]

Then with the "Hub distance" output layer, do a **Joins** by going into *Layer Properties > Joins* and selecting *table2* as the "Join layer". Select the same field with unique values as the "Join field" and *HubName* as the "Target field":

[image: JOINS]

This should join the attributes of the "Hub distance" layer (which contains all attributes from *table1*) with the attributes of *table2*:

[image: Joined attributes]

Comment: Thank you, Joseph! This is exactly what I was looking for. Feels great to have learned something new about QGIS today.

Comment: @flebbelep - Most welcome buddy! I tend to learn something new quite often and yes, it does feel great =)